# Pyspark submit commands through a shell script loop: bad idea?

Tags: shell, apache-spark, pyspark

This isnt a code issue, it's more of a design issue.
I have a shell script that submits a pyspark process. This pyspark process reads hive tables for a specific date, does some work, and writes to a SQL table. The shell script updates the last successful date in a text file on the server. Pretty straightforward.

Now, I want to add the ability to iterate this process over multiple dates. My first instinct was to create a loop in the pyspark code itself. Read, process, write, repeat; all in a single spark-submit command.

Now imagine I'm running it for the dates 1st to 7th June. If my pyspark code fails for a specific day in that range, say 4th June, it will exit the process, throw an error, and my success file doesn't get updated. However, I've still processed data for dates 1st to 3rd. Re-running the process for the entire date range is wasting resources.

So naturally my second instinct is to add a loop in the shell script itself, and submitting spark jobs iteratively. Is this a bad idea? I'm fairly new to pyspark, or Spark as a whole, and I'm trying to understand if this would cause problems.

Alternatively, is there a way to return a date value from spark-submit command to my shell script?